# Print Composer: Finder window disappearing when pressing save button?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mac

I recently updated to 2.6.1 (using mac OS 10.10.1). When I'm in print composer, and I try to save my map (or open a new file, or do anything that brings up a finder window), the window disappears before I can select anything. Which means I can't save any files. I've checked to make sure it's not just popping up behind other windows, and as far as I can tell, its' not.

I've tried redownloading and installing GDAL and Matplotlib just in case. I've restarted (both QGIS and the computer).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please create an issue ticket on the [QGIS tracker](http://issues.qgis.org).

Answer (score 0):

The only very temporary and poor solution I have found is that I have been able to export in SOME VERY LIMITED scales which I set in the Print Composer, i.e. 8171 and 35124.

I have no idea why it works for these scales and not other sorry.